# Kibana 4 RAM consumption

Tags: kibana-4

I installed Kibana 4.3.0 on my VPS having one CPU core and 2GB of RAM running Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Kibana works and my dashboard works as expected, but unfortunately it consumes too much RAM so the VPS begins to swap and has a very high system load.

There is not much data put into ES (about 192 temperature entries per day) so Kibana 4 should not consume too much memory.

Is there any possibility to configure Kibana 4 to consume less RAM, i.e. 256MB at the maximum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this thread I found a solution for the memory consumption: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/5170

It seems to be a Node.js problem. Changing the last line in bin/kibana start script to

```
exec "${NODE}" --max-old-space-size=100  "${DIR}/src/cli" ${@}
```

as suggested in the thread helped.

Comment: Please select this as the correct answer if it worked. The file is `bin/kibana` and you can also use the `NODE_OPTIONS="${NODE_OPTIONS:=--max-old-space-size=500}"`directive